# How to put running Java runnable JAR process in Bash background using Runtime.exec

Tags: java, bash, shell, executable-jar, runtime.exec

I am trying to run a Java runnable JAR, do something in it in the foreground, and then make it go into the background... I use the following *putInBackground* method in the code to look for a process matching the 'command' String, get its PID, send SIGSTOP to it, *bg*, and *disown -h* it... I have the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class CommandUtil
{

    private static final String GPID = "ps -ef | grep '%s' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'";
    private static final String PCMD = GPID + " | xargs %s";
    private static final String STOP = "kill -19";
    private static final String BCKG = "bg";
    private static final String DSON = "disown -h";

    private static Runtime runtime;
    private static Process process;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String outputLine;

    private static boolean runtime() {
        return (runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()) != null;
    }

    public static boolean putInBackground(String command) {
        if(runCmdPid(command, STOP)) {
            if(runCommand(BCKG)) {
                return runCommand(DSON);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean runCmdPid(String command, String xargs) {
        return runCommand(String.format(PCMD, command, xargs));
    }

    public static boolean runCommand(String command) {
        if(runtime() && command != null && !command.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                process = runtime.exec(command);
                process.waitFor();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                while ((outputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(outputLine);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

 }
```

...unfortunately when I try to put the JAR from calling class into the background using the above CommandUtil class (remotely via SSH), I get the following output:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bg": error=2, No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)  at
>   find.me.home.tools.CommandUtil.runCommand(CommandUtil.java:42)    at
>   find.me.home.tools.CommandUtil.putInBackground(CommandUtil.java:27)
>     at find.me.home.FindMeAndelsbolig.main(FindMeAndelsbolig.java:84)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:248)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 11 more

I would appreciate any help rendered here... I know it would be much easier to just run a bash script, and then add & at the end of the command to put it in the background, but I need to allow password input beforehand. Also, I don't think I can run it from a bash script as I have to wait for th password input before putting it into the background.

Anyhow, thank you, anyone and all, and enjoy your day! :)

Sincerely,
Piotr.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path for `bg` > `/usr/bin/bg`

Comment: @derlarsschneider unfortunately the result is the same :/

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/bg": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 (...)